# Is it possible to use the submit function to save textareas to a new file?

Tags: javascript, html, onclick

I am trying to see if it is possible to use a script to write two text areas to a single file when clicking "Submit" on my page? (For total context, these are HTML pages being hosted locally on the machine and are not being housed on a server anywhere)

I successfully learned to erase the two text areas with javascript:eraseText and having that button set the values to "".

I have been looking for an option but I don't know if I'm asking it the right way.

Any help is appreciated.

*Edits for clarity*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>

function eraseText() {
    document.getElementById("one").value = "";
    document.getElementById("two").value = "";
}

function submit() {


}

</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="boxes">

<textarea id='one' rows="20" cols="70">
</textarea>
<p></p>
<textarea id='two' rows="20" cols="70">
</textarea>

</div>

<p></p>
<input type="button" value="Clear" onclick="javascript:eraseText();">
<input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="javascript:submit();">

</body>
</html>
```

So I'd like to click submit and have the values in "one" and "two" parsed to a single HTML output.

Comment: When you say "a single file", are you referring to an actual, downloadable, file?

Comment: That would be an acceptable option. The end result is something as simple as putting information in the two text areas that has basic HTML formatting and I would like to be able to click "Submit" and have it show the result of the formatted HTML together. - So textAreaOne="<b>This is bold</b" and textAreaTwo="<i>This is italic.</i>" and clicking submit would show it as one page with each line.

Comment: it's unclear to me what you want, can you give an example?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript: Create and save file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13405129/javascript-create-and-save-file)

Comment: @SamApostel - I edited my post to show clarity.

Comment: @AliAdlavaran - thanks for the link! I'm gonna check those out now

Comment: I'm sorry to tell you this but this is extremely basic stuff (i.e. not SO material). You're also asking for how to create/save a new file (which is why somebody marked this as duplicate of a question it turns out yours isn't a duplicate of), then in your comment say you actually want to something completely different, namely display the combined text on the page. Just look into `.innerHTML`. Also, you don't need to add `javascript:` for `onclick` attributes, since the click handling is already done by JS.

Comment: @ChrisG Yeah, the original intent was to have it save to an html file so that I could have a trail of all the different ones I have submitted. So in the clarification I did want to point out that even just displaying it would work too. I'll definitely keep it in mind for future questions as if I had searched for saving the output I would have found the other thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>

function eraseText() {
    document.getElementById("one").value = "";
    document.getElementById("two").value = "";
}

function submit() {
    var combined = "";
    combined += document.getElementById("one").value;
    combined += document.getElementById("two").value;
    document.getElementById("destination").innerHTML = combined;
}

</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="boxes">

<textarea id='one' rows="20" cols="70">
</textarea>
<p></p>
<textarea id='two' rows="20" cols="70">
</textarea>

</div>

<p id="destination"></p>
<input type="button" value="Clear" onclick="eraseText();">
<input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="submit();">

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You should add a closing quote to `document.getElementById("destination).innerHTML = combined;` so that it becomes `document.getElementById("destination").innerHTML = combined;`. Good answer though

Comment: @Max tnx, didn't see the typo ;p

Comment: @SamApostel Thank you so much! I just tried it and it worked! That is so great :D Thank you so much for the help. I upvoted, but I'm still too new for it to count publicly I guess.

Comment: @Max Thanks for your input below and the help on the closing quote. You are equally as awesome :D

Comment: @adrian ah yess, keep coding. Keep trying! Don’t forget to look at other people’s work ☺️

Comment: @SamApostel for sure! I absolutely love GitHub. Using some of the frameworks there has been so useful. I have been watching a tutorial on webscraping using Python and BeautifulSoup also. I tend to jump around a bit, but I love the CLI on the Mac and I have loved learning all I have so far. The helpful people in the community have only made it even more enjoyable

Answer (score 0):

The solution that doesn't use any server-side code to accomplish this, if I understand your question correctly, is  as follows.

Let's write what your HTML probably currently looks like.

```
<textarea></textarea>
<textarea></textarea>
<button type="submit">Submit</button>
```

Let's first add an output area where the preview will appear. This could be a `<div></div>` element.

Now, add `id` attributes to all the elements (I'll use the IDs "a", "b", "c", and "d", and the output DIV. This allows JavaScript code to easily grab a certain element using the Document Object Model.

Once done, this is the code

```js
document.getElementById("d").addEventListener("click", function(){ // do this when element with id `d` is clicked
    document.getElementById("c").innerHTML = // set the output element's inner HTML to...
                                            document.getElementById("a").value + document.getElementById("b").value 
})
```

```html
<textarea id="a"></textarea>
<textarea id="b"></textarea>
<div id="c"></div>
<button id="d">Submit</button>
```

`document.getElementById(IDGOESHERE)` returns a JavaScript object representing the element with that ID. `.addEventListener` binds something to an event happening (in this case, the click event triggers a function to be called).

That function takes the values of the two textareas, and adds (joins) them together using the `+` operator, which concatenates with strings.

It then assigns this HTML using the `.innerHTML` property of the output element.

I'm not sure if this is what you wanted, so please do clarify if it isn't.

Comment: I think you shouldn't go into eventListeners here... good explanation though

Comment: Mmhm, I'm pretty sure using `javascript:STUFF` isn't considered good code anymore, though

Comment: you’re correct! I updated my answer to comply with the latest standards (I think). If you find anything else, I’ll gladly change it ☺️

Comment: Yeah, the code now is good! I didn't want to use onclick in case they wanted to bind more than one listener later in development (i.e. using good practices early on), but onclick works fine. Yay - collaboration works!!